# Save user input as it is - Ruby on Rails

Tags: c++, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create an Online Judge where users will write/paste c++ code to evaluate it. I'm using rails 6 and **Ruby 2.6.1** . The problem is users' input can contain any type characters **\n**,**\t** etc . I need to save it to a cpp file as it is. For example a user is submitting the following code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World\n";
}
```

**I am using the following Ruby method to save the user input to a file**

`system("echo '#{params[:code]}' > code.cpp")`

My expected output is to be same as the user input. But I'm getting the following output to the saved file.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout << "Hello World
";
}
```

Which is problematic, because it results in compilation error. So my question is how can I **SAFELY** save the users' input as it is.

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/5910058)

Comment: There is absolutely no reason why you would use system to create a file in ruby. https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/File.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an actual Ruby method:

```
File.open('code.cpp', 'w') { |f| f.write(params[:code]) }
```

Or shorter:

```
File.write('code.cpp', params[:code])
```